# Authorization error while trying to upload image from browser to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm following the steps mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTExamples.html#HTTPPOSTExamplesFileUpload) to upload a file directly to my s3 bucket from my browser.

my html file is below

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="http://<my_bucket_name>.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Key to upload: <input type="input" name="key" value="user/kpms/" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://<my_bucket_name>.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html" />
    Content-Type: <input type="input" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-meta-uuid" value="14365123651274" />
    Tags for File: <input type="input" name="x-amz-meta-tag" value="" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="<my access key>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value="" id = "policy"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Signature" value="UjaqquTAeFA13BWFdwh4pcdfgFlTpH3Cs+7o1M55G7E=" />
    File: <input type="file" name="file" /> <br />
    <!-- The elements after this will be ignored -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      temp = '{ "expiration": "2018-12-01T12:00:00.000Z","conditions":{"bucket": "<my_bucket_name>"},["starts-with", "$key", "user/kpms/"],{"acl": "public-read"},{"success_action_redirect": "http://file.upload.from.browser.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],{"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""]  ]}'
  document.getElementById('policy').value = temp
  </script>
</html>
```

I used [this](https://www.base64encode.org/) to do a utf-8 base64 encoding of my policy and [this](https://www.liavaag.org/English/SHA-Generator/HMAC/) to a SHA-256 base 64 encoding of the encoded policy.

my policy is below

```
{ "expiration": "2018-12-01T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "<my_bucket>"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/kpms/"],
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://<my_bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
    {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""]
  ]
}
```

When I submit the request I get the following message

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>
The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
</Message>
<RequestId>C207B264B1B0E50E</RequestId>
<HostId>
tTJ8hD8qcqlzZf/7s6TR6cFd9fF1HOLFRI7p6deyyIcM63DSFoKHSMmYq9FL9WulaPVa5DJAmOQ=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Where did I go wrong or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Signature V2. The error states that it's no longer supported, and that you should use Signature V4

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTExamples.html#HTTPPOSTExamplesFileUpload

> The request authentication discussed in this section is based on AWS
>   Signature Version 2, a protocol for authenticating inbound API
>   requests to AWS services.
>
> Amazon S3 now supports Signature Version 4, a protocol for
>   authenticating inbound API requests to AWS services, in all AWS
>   regions. At this time, AWS regions created before January 30, 2014
>   will continue to support the previous protocol, Signature Version 2.
>   Any new regions after January 30, 2014 will support only Signature
>   Version 4 and therefore all requests to those regions must be made
>   with Signature Version 4. For more information, see Examples:
>   Browser-Based Upload using HTTP POST (Using AWS Signature Version 4)
>   in the Amazon Simple Storage Service API Reference.

Comment: You might want to add a link to the source of your blockquote, and preserve the inline link to *"see Examples."*

Comment: Oops, yes, I see that now.